# Appending a new row to an existing dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to insert a new record to a data frame and am getting this error - `DataFrame constructor not Properly called`.

This is my code,

```
import pandas as pd

#defining the dataframe
dfHeader = { 'Name': [], 'Daily': [],'Weekly': [],'Monthly': [],'Yearly': [],
             'Area': [], 'Latitude':[] , 'Longitude':[] ,'Amenity': [] }

dFrame = pd.DataFrame(dfHeader)
print(dFrame)
Name = "NA"
DailyPrice = "NA"
WeeklyPrice = "NA"
MonthlyPrice = "NA"
YearlyPrice = "NA"
Area = "NA"
latitude = "NA"
longitude = "NA"
Amenity = "NA"

row = (Name, DailyPrice, WeeklyPrice, MonthlyPrice, YearlyPrice, Area, latitude, longitude, Amenity)

print(row)

dFrame = dFrame.append(pd.DataFrame(row))
```

Kindly help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to add a single row:

```
In [136]: dFrame.loc[len(dFrame)] = row

In [137]: dFrame
Out[137]:
  Amenity Area Daily Latitude Longitude Monthly Name Weekly Yearly
0      NA   NA    NA       NA        NA      NA   NA     NA     NA
```

NOTE: usually it's much better, faster, less memory consuming (it depends...) to collect the data first into list of lists and then to call `pd.DataFrame()` constructor **once**:

```
In [138]: data = [row, np.arange(9)]

In [139]: cols = 'Amenity Area Daily Latitude Longitude Monthly Name Weekly Yearly'.split()

In [140]: df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)

In [141]: df
Out[141]:
  Amenity Area Daily Latitude Longitude Monthly Name Weekly Yearly
0      NA   NA    NA       NA        NA      NA   NA     NA     NA
1       0    1     2        3         4       5    6      7      8
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a `DataFrame` from a tuple. You can, however, create a `Series` from a tuple, and have the indicies be the columns of `dFrame`:

```
dFrame.append(pd.Series(row, index=dfHeader.keys()), ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Strange, dFrame still appears empty.

Comment: This does not add to dFrame in place. This creates a new version. You have to set dFrame equal to what I gave you.